# .net Regex to look ahead and eliminate strings in advance that dont contain certain characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am Using .Net Flavor of Regex.

Suppose i have a string 123456789AB
and i want to match AB (Could be any two Capital letters) only if the string part containing numbers(123456789) has 5 and 8 in it.
So what i came up with was
(?=5)(?=8)([A-Z]{2}) 
But this is not working.
After some trail error on RegexStorm

I got to 
(?=(.*5))(?=(.*8))[A-Z]{2}

What i am expecting is it will start matching from the start of the string as look ahead does not consume any characters.
But the part "[A-Z]{2}" does not move ahead to match AB in the input string.
My question is why is that so?
i know replacing it with .*[A-Z]{2} will make it move ahead but then the string matched has entire string in it.
What is the solution in this case other than putting word part ([A-Z]{2}) in a separate group and then catching only that group.

Comment: Maybe `(?<=5\S*?)(?<=8\S*?)[A-Z]{2}` will do? Or `(?s)(?<=5.*?)(?<=8.*?)[A-Z]{2}`. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%28%3f%3c%3d5.*%3f%29%28%3f%3c%3d8.*%3f%29%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d&i=123456789AB). "*the part containing numbers*" - what is *part*?

Comment: If you need AND relationship between the checks, then you need to use separate lookbehinds

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks .that works...But Any inputs on what i am missing in look ahead would be appreciated....

Comment: I added the details to the  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lookaheads* check for the pattern match immediately to the right of the current position in the string. `(?=(.*5))(?=(.*8))` matches a location that is immediately followed with any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then 5 and then  - at the same position - another similar check if performed but requiring `8` after any zero or more chars, as many as possible.

You may use as many as **lookbehinds** as there are required substrings **before** the two letters:

```
(?s)(?<=5.*?)(?<=8.*?)[A-Z]{2}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3D5.%2A%3F%29%28%3F%3C%3D8.%2A%3F%29%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D&i=123456789AB)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - makes the `.` match newline characters, too
- `(?<=5.*?)` - a location that is immediately preceded with `5` and then 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `(?<=8.*?)` - a location that is immediately preceded with `8` and then 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two ASCII uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to "unfold" what you expect to match using exclusionary character classes and alternation of match order. Not pretty, but pretty fast:

```
(?<=\b[^58]*?(?:5[^8]*8|8[^5]*5)[^A-Z]*?)[A-Z]{2}
```